# Should we really divert all software recommendations?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

In the review queue I just stumbled upon [a question about a translator app for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678461/is-there-a-translator-like-translateit-under-ubuntu) , which is on the way to be closed as "off topic".

Is closing and pointing to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ really the way we should go?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:

As long the question is not asking for "the best", I would say it is on topic here. OP just asks for "a" translator of a certain type for Ubuntu, which is a question about (using)... *Ubuntu* I would say.

#### the Help Centre

The *Help Centre* also seems to leave no doubt the question is on- topic:

> Questions that you may ask:
>
> Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.

There are many questions here that *might* generate a better answer somewhere else, but there will be always an overlap of topics, and the decision where to ask is OP's.

Comment: I agree, but obviously others don't - the question is closed as "off topic" by now.

Comment: @guntbert I must say I am quite surprised by the support the close vote got. I cannot explain it from the rules to be found in the help centre, especially "Questions you may ask": *Running third-party applications on Ubuntu*. I will propose to reopen.